# Stream PyGame Webcam to Glade interface

Tags: python, gtk, pygame, pygtk, glade

I'm currently working on a GUI for a telescope.
I've got a webCam connected via USB to a raspberry pi.
A small python-script is reading the imageData to String an is sending it via socket to my pc. Now I want to display this imageString in a GTK image.

```
def updateWebCamPic(self, imageString):
    print "update"
    img = Image.open(StringIO(imageString))
    self.image.set_from_pixbuf(self.image2pixbuf(img))
    print "updatet"

def getPixBufRGB8Bit(self, im):
    arr = numpy.array(im)
    return GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_data((arr, Gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, 8))

def image2pixbuf(im):
    """Convert Pillow image to GdkPixbuf"""
    data = im.tobytes()
    w, h = im.size
    data = GLib.Bytes.new(data)
    pix = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_bytes(data, GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB,
            False, 8, w, h, w * 3)
    return pix
```

But I get the following error:

```
raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

[EDIT]:

```
if str(received[0]).startswith("<|Image|>"):
    image=received[0][9:]
    self.parrent.updateWebCamPic(image)
```

Comment: always put full error message. Which line in code generate this error ? Probably `Image.open()`. `Image.open()` expect data in format PNG, JPG, GIF, etc.

Comment: see [pygame.image.tostring](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.tostring) : `string` could be use with `fromstring()` in other Python modules

Comment: Its in Image.open() but how can I convert the pygame Image to png?

Comment: Or how can I display a surface ?

Comment: you probably use `PIL` or `Pillow` then check `PIL.image.fromstring()` or rather [frombytes()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes)